# Installing only registry settings of program or game?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, portable

Is it possible to copy the install directory of program or game between different computers instead installing it all over again, and only install the registry settings for the program/game? Will the program or game work this way?

My question is how to save the registry settings and then install them on the new computer?

I want to do this with games like Need for Speed, The Sims and some programs.

Comment: This depends on the application itself.  This is a horrible idea the amount of time you would spend doing this could be sent to just installing the games.

Comment: @Ramhound , but there can be more horrible things, which make you do it ;) For example you have a great game with size 8GB and you have lost its installation disk... And your internet is too slow to download it...

Comment: Which NFS and Sims do you want?? As I remember, old NFSes were easy to move.

Answer (score 2):

It is depended on how good the software keeps its own security.

1) If it's a "free" software/game, then probably copying files and reg keys will help you.
2) If it checks its "activation key" (or smtg like it) just by using some registry keys and files, then copying files and keys will solve the problem.
3) If a software has a good security (for example, it checks hardware unique serial number, encrypts, stores in registry...), then copying registry keys and files will not help you. Then only cracking, disassembling and debugging will help.

For extracting registry keys use tools like [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html).
If a software keeps some "useful" info in files out of its folder, then attach [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to that process and see where are that files and folders.